Is std an unqualified id?
I was going over chapter 7 Templates of Bjarne's A Tour of C++, 3rd edition [Chapter 7 is for templates but there is only a declaration there. I had to go to Chapter 5, p. 59 to get an implementation] and I tried writing out the code for a Vector with an std::initializer_list. I got this error
error: expected unqualified-id before ‘static_cast’
   47 |     elem{new T[lst.size()]}, sz{std::static_cast<int>(lst.size())}
                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~

while compiling this addition
template <typename T>
Vector<T>::Vector(std::initializer_list<T> lst):
    elem{new T[lst.size()]}, sz{std::static_cast<int>(lst.size())}
{

    std::copy(lst.begin(), lst.end(), elem); // copy from lst into elem (§13.5) 

}

I was under the impression that std:: would "qualify" whatever comes after it. The error implies that std itself is not qualified but isn't it in the global scope and can be distinguished from other variables included in the global scope?
Note: The code from Chapter 5 doesn't have std::. However, the author wrote other functions with possibly using directive or declaration for std methods to avoid clutter. I have just been adding std everywhere and I discovered today that static_cast doesn't need it.

static_cast is a language feature and is not part of the std:: standard library

std is a namespace, and static_cast is a keyword. The two don't mix. (Kind of like writing std::while( ... ) and expecting the resulting error message to make sense.)

On the other side, the newer std::bit_cast is indeed in the std namespace! I find this not coherent with other casts. I know it is not a keyword, but from the user perspective, nothing is gramatically different between static_cast and bit_cast.

static_cast is a language keyword and can't be used as an identifier. It is not a function or template in the standard library namespace (which is called std). It is not a function or template at all. It is part of the language's core syntax.
When you write something like
X::Y

then Y is an unqualified-id, but X::Y is a qualified-id. Typically, when X stands alone it is also an unqualified-id.
The compiler is telling you that whatever comes after :: should be an unqualified-id, e.g. someFunctionName, someTemplateName<int>, etc.
It is saying that, because every qualified-id must end in an unqualified-id after the last ::. Something else like the static_cast keyword (which isn't an unqualified-id) can't appear after the last :: in a qualified-id.
See https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id.qual#nt:qualified-id for the relevant production rule of the language grammar.

Here, static_cast is a keyword, so it doesn't belong to the std namespace. That's why the error is showing expected unqualified-id before 'static_cast'.
In simpler terms, you're using an identifier std::static_cast that doesn't exist.
The std:: namespace is used to qualify identifiers within the C++ Standard Library (like std::vector, std::copy, etc.).
See more about scope resolution operator https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.3?topic=expressions-scope-resolution-operator-c-only
See How do you properly use namespaces in C++? for use of namespaces generally.
